# Quartz.net Manually trigger job from Web API

Tags: quartz.net-3.0

I realize this has sort of been asked before but I want to get a clear confirmation.

I have a Windows Service running the Quartz.Net Scheduler. Jobs and Triggers have been created.

We will have an angular web client that will at times, need to fire jobs manually.

So in a Web API Controller, I have code like this:

```
            var properties = new NameValueCollection
            {
                ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
                ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true",
                ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
                ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "myDS",
                ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
                ["quartz.dataSource.NAME.provider"] = "SqlServer",
                ["quartz.dataSource.NAME.connectionString"] = "Server=localhost;Database=QuartzScheduler;Uid=blahuser;Pwd=blahpwd",
                ["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"
            };

            var sched = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties).GetScheduler().Result;

            var jobKey = new JobKey("DailyJob1130EST", "DailyGroup");
            var jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
            jobDataMap.Add("listIds", "33333");

            sched.TriggerJob(jobKey, jobDataMap);
```

The Job Name and Group do exist in the database.

I was hoping that the call to TriggerJob would cause the Scheduler I have running in my windows service, to fire the job. But it doesn't. Nothing happens, not even an error.

BTW, I don't want to use remoting since it requires the full .NET Framework and the help docs say that it is considered unsafe.

If TriggerJob doesn't work, I guess to run a job manually I'd have to add a new trigger to the scheduler to run once, or something???

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways, but one way that I was able to successfully do it was:

```
            var sched = await new StdSchedulerFactory(properties).GetScheduler();

            var jobKey = new JobKey("DailyJob1130EST", "DailyGroup");
            var jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
            jobDataMap.Add("listIds", rInt.ToString());

            var trig = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("RunNowTrigger")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenSecondDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5)))
                .WithDescription("Run Now Trigger")
                .Build();

            sched.TriggerJob(jobKey, jobDataMap);
```

Note: "properties" were my NameValueCollection config information, which I omitted from the sample code. It was nothing out of the ordinary. It just setup the jobStore, dataSource, serializer.type and threadPool.type settings.